# spring data neo4j 4 save randomly generates errors

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have quite complex project that uses Spring Data Neo4j. Everything worked well with version 3 but now, we are trying to migrate to SDN 4 and I have sometimes problems saving a node (I don't use the save depth level so I assume it's by default -1 so everything that changed is saved).
The error log is the following when I run `myNoderepository.save(myNode)`:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.ResultProcessingException: "errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax","message":"Query cannot conclude with MATCH (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 1, column 859 (offset: 858))\n\"MATCH ()-[_0]->() WHERE id(_0)={_0} SET _0+={_0_props}  WITH _0 MATCH ()-[_10]->() WHERE id(_10)={_10} SET _10+={_10_props}  WITH _0,_10 MATCH ()-[_11]->() WHERE id(_11)={_11} WITH _0,_10 MATCH ()-[_13]->() WHERE id(_13)={_13} SET _13+={_13_props}  WITH _0,_10,_13 MATCH ()-[_15]->() WHERE id(_15)={_15} SET _15+={_15_props}  WITH _0,_10,_13,_15 MATCH ()-[_2]->() WHERE id(_2)={_2} SET _2+={_2_props}  WITH _0,_10,_13,_15,_2 MATCH ()-[_20]->() WHERE id(_20)={_20} SET _20+={_20_props}  WITH _0,_10,_13,_15,_2,_20 MATCH ()-[_22]->() WHERE id(_22)={_22} SET _22+={_22_props}  WITH _0,_10,_13,_15,_2,_20,_22 MATCH ()-[_24]->() WHERE id(_24)={_24} WITH _0,_10,_13,_15,_2,_20,_22 MATCH ()-[_4]->() WHERE id(_4)={_4} SET _4+={_4_props}  WITH _0,_10,_13,_15,_2,_20,_22,_4 MATCH ()-[_6]->() WHERE id(_6)={_6} SET _6+={_6_props}  WITH _0,_10,_13,_15,_2,_20,_22,_4,_6 MATCH ()-[_8]->() WHERE id(_8)={_8}\"\n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ^"}]}
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse.parseErrors(JsonResponse.java:165) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse.parseColumns(JsonResponse.java:139) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.JsonResponse.initialiseScan(JsonResponse.java:75) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.RowModelResponse.initialiseScan(RowModelResponse.java:63) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.RowModelResponse.<init>(RowModelResponse.java:37) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.response.SessionResponseHandler.updateObjects(SessionResponseHandler.java:87) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:69) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:43) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:386) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy251.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.save(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:46) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy303.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

The error log doesn't say a lot to me as it seems it might be someting wrong under the save method of repository...

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the entity you're trying to save. Could you upgrade to use neo4j-ogm 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT? It contains quite a few bug fixes but we've never seen this one before tbh

Comment: Thanks @Luanne :) I upgraded the ogm to the version 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT. Now, I don't have the described error but null pointer exception when i try to exectute `myNoderepository.save(myNode)`. I suspect that I do sth wrong with deleting relationships in my graph. Previously (in SDN3), when I wanted to add relation I just executed: `myRelRepository.save(myRel)` and to delete: `myRelRepository.delete(myRel)`. Now (in SDN4) , when I want to persist relation, I create the relation object, add it to the node and save node: `myNoderepository.save(myNode)`, but I still delete the relations the same way..

Comment: I am going to examine how to delete relations in SDN4 and work on this error. Maybe, there is already somewhere an example that might help me @Luanne ?

Comment: When deleting relations, keep your object references in sync too- delete them from the entities. So if you've deleted `myRel`, also remove it from  `myNode`